# AHK: read form *.ini

Tags: keyboard, autohotkey, ini, flags, remap

This code from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687 ... autohotkey

My question is:
Is it possible to divide the code into two files?

- Part 1 into "*.ahk"
- Part 2 into "*.ini"

If someone could show me how to do this, I would be very grateful!

```
; --------------------------------------------------------------part  1

#SingleInstance Force
Flag:=0
Return

^+!F7::
Flag:=0
TrayTip, AutoHotKey, Keyboard setting Default, 1
Return

^+!F4::
Flag:=1
TrayTip, AutoHotKey, Keyboard setting A, 1
Return

^+!F8::
Flag:=2
TrayTip, AutoHotKey, Keyboard setting B, 1
Return
; ----------------------------------------------------------part  2
#If (Flag=1)
x::SoundBeep, 500, 100
k::l
#If

#If (Flag=2)
x::SoundBeep, 2000, 100
l::Numpad5
#If
```

Comment: https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/IniRead.htm

Comment: any help pleas.

Answer (score 0):

Sure it is possible, but I don't really get the point of storing autohotkey code in a .ini file.
Use [#Include](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_Include.htm).

**part1.ahk**

```
;--------------------------------------------------------------part 1
#SingleInstance Force
Flag:=0
Return

^+!F7::
Flag:=0
TrayTip, AutoHotKey, Keyboard setting Default, 1
Return

^+!F4::
Flag:=1
TrayTip, AutoHotKey, Keyboard setting A, 1
Return

^+!F8::
Flag:=2
TrayTip, AutoHotKey, Keyboard setting B, 1
Return

#Include part2.ini
```

**part2.ini**

```
; ----------------------------------------------------------part  2
#If (Flag=1)
x::SoundBeep, 500, 100
k::l
#If

#If (Flag=2)
x::SoundBeep, 2000, 100
l::Numpad5
#If
```

Comment: I am very grateful for your help, thank you very much.